# Recovery on Failure for a Windows Service Application

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-services

I am having trouble getting the feature recovery on failure to work for my Windows Service Application. I set in up to restart the application on first failure. Then to test in I use this line of code

```
   System.Environment.Exit(-1)
```

This causes the application to end okay but it doesn't restart.

Comment: That's a clean exit, it doesn't count as "failure".  Try raising an exception instead.

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks. I cannot mark it as answer because it is a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonable to suppose that a service process exiting without setting the service status to stopped would constitute a failure.  However, that isn't the case.  (Perhaps for backwards compatibility; there might be too many third-party services that such a change would break.)

However, if the process exits as the result of an unhandled exception, that is considered a service failure and triggers the recovery options.  So if you want to cause the service to fail, raise an exception (and don't catch it).